# listView filter search

Tags: android, arrays, string, filter

I was looking to filter a listView by an editText.
My ListView is populate by an ArrayString, and when I filter it everything goes right. But I have a problem to recognize the element clicked. When I filter the listView and I click on the item filtered I want to have the number of the row in the original arrayString in order to make an Intent. Whit my code when I click the item in the filtered arrayString the row is 0 and it's not correct. If I search "Anche Se Pesa" I want to return the row 2 like the position in the original ArrayString.

```
<string-array name="titoli">
        <item>An Val Dondona</item>
        <item>Anche Mio Padre</item>
        <item>Anche Se Pesa</item>
        <item>Andremo In Francia</item>
        <item>Aprite Le Porte</item>
        <item>Arda Berghem</item>
        <item>Ascoltate Amici Cari</item>
        <item>Ave, O Vergine</item>
        <item>Aver na Figlia Sola Soletta</item>
        <item>Ancora sti quatro</item>
        <item>Andouma Prou</item>

    </string-array>
```

Here Is the code

```
public class activity_titoli extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btt_backHome;
    ListView lV_titoli;
    EditText eT_search;
    private ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_titoli);

        btt_backHome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btt_backHome);
        lV_titoli = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lV_titoli);
        eT_search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eT_search);

        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.titoli, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        lV_titoli.setAdapter(adapter);

        final Intent to_Home = new Intent (this , Activity_Main.class);

        eT_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                          int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
                (activity_titoli.this).adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);
            }
        });

        btt_backHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(to_Home);
            }
        });

        lV_titoli.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Log.e("Element: " , Integer.toString(i));

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
lV_titoli.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Resources res = getResources();
                List<CharSequence> list = Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.titoli));
                Log.e("Element: " , Integer.toString(list.indexOf(adapter.filgetItem(i))));

            }
        });
```

Hope this helps